# Why do these parameters not get passed to the Promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm having difficulty with async/await and Promises in ES6.
In short, I pass in two parameters to an async function that returns a Promise. I can't seem to access the two variables inside the Promise function.

```
var outside = async function(foo, bar){
    var res;
    console.log("outside:", foo, bar); // "outside: FOO BAR
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log("inside:", foo, bar); // undefined
        resolve(res)
        return;
    });
}; 

var outsideCall = await outside("FOO", "BAR");
```

Comment: `undefined` as in no console.log or as in `inside: undefined undefined`?

Comment: Where are you running this? Are you using ES6 directly or transpiling?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry.  The problem was that I wasn't sending the right information for "FOO" and "BAR".  Promises have nothing to do with it. :( Sorry for wasting your time.